# Spark Save DataSet partitionby File Already Exists Error

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, parquet, apache-spark-dataset

I have a DataSet which was constructed in the following way:

```
 Encoder<MyDomain> encoder= Encoders.bean(MyDomain.class);
 Dataset<MyDomain> stdDS = sc.createDataset(filteredRecords.rdd(), encoder);
 Dataset<Row> rowDataset = stdDS.withColumn("idHash", stdDS.col("id").substr(0, 5));
```

I am then trying to output the dataset by doing:

```
        rowDataset.write().partitionBy("keep", "idHash").save("test.parquet");
```

When I only partition by "keep" everything works correctly, then I partition by both "keep" and "idHash" I get:

```
File already exists: file:/C:/dev/test.parquet/_temporary/0/_temporary/attempt_201701191219_0001_m_000000_0/keep=true/idHash=0a/part-r-00000-2c2e0494-f6a7-47d7-88e2-f49dffb608d1.snappy.parquet
```

How can I get my DataSet to properly output using multiple partitions.  The folder is empty to start with.  Also this error is happening when I run on my local machine, in production this data will be output to S3 so any solution needs to work both against a local filesystem and AWS S3.

Thanks,
Nathan

Comment: Did you try to put this `write().mode("append")` or `write().mode("overwrite")`?

Comment: I tried append but the same error occurred, I wouldn't think either option would be needed since there is no output data to start with.

Comment: Did you get a solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
rowDataset.repartition("keep", "idHash").write().partitionBy("keep", "idHash").save("test.parquet");
```